# Spring Security 3 - Multiple Secuirty Filters after First postion

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using spring 3 and implementing a series of custom filters in the security chain.  I need to call a series of already implemented filters after the FIRST position.  If I try to list two filters in the same position (after="FIRST") the context fails to load with the error stating that position is already in use and there is a conflict.

How do I implement a series of custom filters to be called after the "FIRST" position?

(I prefer not to refactor the filters because they are pretty detailed)

Answer (score 2):

If the conflict is between these two filters then you can define a composite filter:

```
 <bean id="customFilters" class="org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter">
<property name="filters">
    <list>
        <ref bean="customfilter1"/>
        <ref bean="customfilter2"/>
    </list>
</property>
```

Add it to your filter chain like this:

```
 <security:http ...>
 <security:custom-filter after="FIRST" ref="customFilters" />
 ....
  </security:http>
```

Comment: Thank you ..Exactly what I was looking for... I ended up creating a sub-chain within one of my filters , implementing FilterChain and passing it to the other filters, and only once the other filters finished, did i advance the main filter chain.  However, your solution is better.